# Crawling delay for Google Cached Pages

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler

I'm trying to download an offline website which is still cached by Google. I built a script in Python which does the job following a list of links in a txt file. The problem is that Google ban my IP after more or less 30 pages downloaded. Can't figure out why, since I wait a random time of 10-60 seconds between two downloads:

```
    sleep_time = randint(10,60)
    sleep(sleep_time)
```

and I also use a different User Agent for urllib2 (I use the one that I see on http://whatsmyuseragent.com).

Why Google keep banning me and why he can detect me if my timing is perfectly "human"?

Comment: google uses more advanced anti-scraping measures than just timing delays

Comment: I know but I read a lot of articles about it and all of them say that if you set a "reasonable" crawling delay everything is ok and google doesn't ban you, so i'm guessing why I'm having this problem.

Comment: You can try the google API. The new one needs a dev key. You can use the old one.But it's limited. If you implement your own change the user-agent, sleep in between and most importantly *hope for the best.*